# Days between dates for any day-count basis in R

Tags: r, days

Is there a function in R that calculates the number of days between two dates for any day-count basis? I am looking for something similar to the Matlab's daysdif function.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/daysdif.html

In particular, I am interested in counting the number of days on the 360-day year, the equivalent of Excel's days360 function.

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/days360.php

Is there a package that contains any helpful functions?

Comment: Look into `lubridate`

Comment: `lubridate` seems not to have the functionality that I am looking for

Comment: See the `PCICt` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that suit you?

```
> as.POSIXct("2015-09-08")-as.POSIXct("2015-09-06")
Time difference of 2 days
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2015-09-08")-as.POSIXct("2015-09-06"))
[1] 2
```

**EDIT**

With `lubridate` package one may create such function

```
> library(lubridate)
> 
> FACTOR_30_360 <- function(date1, date2){
+    stopifnot(is.POSIXct(date1) | is.POSIXct(date2))
+    
+    (360*(year(date2)-year(date1)) + 30*(month(date2) - month(date1))
+     + day(date2)-day(date1))/360
+ }
> 
> FACTOR_30_360(as.POSIXct("2015-09-08"),
+               as.POSIXct("2015-09-10"))
[1] 0.005555556
```

**EDIT2**

Or try this package [RQuantLib](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQuantLib/RQuantLib.pdf) - page10